# Orientation of face normals for 3D polytope

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, computational-geometry

I have a 3d Polytope. I need to find the normal for each face of the polytope and normals should have consistent orientation, either outward or inward. I am using 'faceNormals' function of MATLAB for finding the normals. 
How can I find orientation for the normals and make them consistent ?

Comment: can you give an example of the input and output? post the code you already have.

Comment: Input : polytope_vertices - [-5 -1.25 -5;  -5 -0.5 -5; 2.5 -1.25 -5;  5   -1.25 -3.75; 5 -1.25 -0.83; 5 -0.73  -1.176; -5 -1.25  2.5; -5 -0.96  2.31; -5 0  -2.5;  0  0  0]
polytope_faces - 
[1   2  3], [ 5  4  6], [1   7   8   9   2], [1   3   4  5   7], [2   3   4   6  10   9], [5   6  10   8   7], [8      10]
normals_per_face  - [0         0   -1 ; 1.0000         0         0; -1.0000         0         0;   0   -1.0000         0;  -0.0976   -0.9759    0.1952;    0.2673    0.5345    0.8018;  0.0976   -0.9759   -0.1952 ]

Comment: you should put this into your question, preferably in matlab syntax. describe what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: I have normals of each face. I just want to know their orientation, whether they are outward or inwards.